# How to adjust Button size according to screen size

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, xml-layout

I am new to android and I was making a layout with 2 Rows of buttons where in each row there are to 3 buttons. I wanted my application's UI to be compatible with any screen size. So I got Screen width and Height in px. Since I haven't worked before in android I do not know should I adjust buttons with px or with dp in order for it to work on any device?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use pixels. You should use `LinearLayout` with `layout_weight` s.

Here is an example with 6 equal sized buttons in 2 rows. The key point here is to have `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 2" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 3" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 4" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 5" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 6" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes I did use LinearLayout but the problem with this was that it doesn't adjust size of buttons (I have lager buttons and larger buttons in smaller layouts overlap other buttons or do not show the button entirely)

Comment: I updated the answer providing a layout with 6 buttons with 3 in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the layout with 2 row ,each row containing 3 buttons

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="test" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="test" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="test" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="test" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="test" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="test" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```